# How multi is Wordpress Multisite?

Tags: php, wordpress, scalability

We're looking at how to build a large number of sites built out of common components. Each site will be relatively simple, and not involve much user interaction, but we are expecting a large number of them - up to 500. Each site will have different plugins enabled, have its own theme etc.

Wordpress has a multisite feature that allows multiple sites to be served from the one Wordpress installation. We're considering using this as a way of managing these 500 related sites.

What kind of limits are we likely to hit? Does it make any sense to push it to this scale? We are looking at 1000s of logged-in users and 10,000s of anonymous concurrent sessions for the group of sites as a whole - each site has a peak at a different time.

Comment: Considering WordPress.com runs Multisite - I'm sure you'll be fine :)

Comment: https://wordpress.org/search/scalability

Comment: @GavinThomas I'm sure it's possible, but I think it's likely that WordPress.com does some clever things e.g. with database sharding.

Comment: @Jocelyn, thanks, but that link doesn't really help me. I'm after specific limits with multisite, not general Wordpress scaling advice.